# bash - show path, if every word is a palindrome

Tags: bash, find

I need to write program in `bash` using `find` which show all paths, where every path word is a palindrome.

Example:

```
/kajak/aga/ - true
/xyz/zyx/ - false
```

I don't know, how to start with that. Any tips ?

Comment: Can you give a proper example of your actual paths _exactly_ from the output of `find`

Comment: .
./kajak
./aga
./zadanie.sh

Comment: What you have mentioned here are file names and _NOT_ file paths as you mentioned in question. Please clarify on the actual requirment